# jQuery on click event

Tags: jquery, onclick

Why this code doesn't work?

```
jQuery(".ui-accordion-header").on("click", function(event){ ... }
```

And this one works?

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".ui-accordion-header", function(event){ ... }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Probably `.ui-accordion-header` doesn't exist when you run this

Answer (score 2):

The first line only works if the `.ui-accordion-header` already exists in the dom. Sometimes the elements are dynamically created and inserted into the dom. In such scenarios, the listeners are not bound to the newly created elements.

The reason the second way works is because the listener is tied at the `document` level. So whenever any new changes are made inside the document, the listener is still bound.

Comment: I'm creating the elements inside the .ui-accordion-header div by importing data from JSON via Backbone JS.

Comment: You're going to want to wait until the data is loaded and the corresponding dom is created before attaching the jquery listener you have there. Try adding it in the success function of a Backbone fetch.

Answer (score 1):

When you have call like `jQuery(".ui-accordion-header")`, jQuery assigns that method to all the objects that exist as it's loaded (when the page is loaded). So if an object with a class name `ui-accordion-header` isn't a DOM element when the page is set-up, the method won't be assigned to it.

`jQuery(document)` will assign it to the document, which will respond whenever a `.ui-accordion-header` is clicked. Basically, if it's a DOM object that will be created sometime after the page is loaded, stick to `jQuery(document)` methods. By the way, why don't you use `$`? For instance, `$(document)`, `$(".ui-accordion-header")`, etc.